# What happens first - Symfony2 persist

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have been wondering what happens first with symfony2 regarding persistence of entities.

Let's say for example I have a function in my controller which is called when persisting data but also I have a lifecycle call back which runs PrePersist. Which function is run first?

Also if I wish to perform some sort of calculation based on user submitted values (from a form) is it better to do this from within the controller or from within the entity its self, again with a PrePersist callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latin prefix *pre* means “before”. ;) Therefore the PrePersist callback will be applied before persisting.

If you call some functionality on persisting, it depends if the `$EntityManager->persist()` is before or after that. The LifecycleCallback is “atomic” with the persist operation. In detail, this means that your LifecycleCallback is applied before the UnitOfWork computes the modifications which should be written to the DB.

You should also keep in mind that nothing is written to the DB before you call `$EntityManager->flush()`.

As for the calculation: There's no hard rule, but as a rule of thumb:

- If all logic required is available in the context of the entity, and components outside the entity don't need to know about a transformation of the passed value, you can do it inside a getter/setter of the entity.
- As soon as outside components are affected, or you need external services for the modification, you should definitely do it inside a controller or a dedicated management service.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit unclear. Updated post. The EM first applies the pre callbacks, then passes the processed entity to the UOW, which calculates the changeset. I don't know which one has precedence if you register two callbacks on the same entity/field, but I'd assume that they will be processed in chronological order and that it doesn't matter if it's registered as annotation or by method call. However, if it's chronological, then I'd assume that the annotation will be processed first, as it is loaded with the entity, which is much earlier than what may happen in your controller.